# Why Rails server starts different ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

Can someone tell me why

```
salvator:edu uko$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

and

```
salvator:edu uko$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-11-20 15:26:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-11-20 15:26:30] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin11.0]
[2011-11-20 15:26:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=562 port=3000
```

ruby versions are different? Can I specify ruby on server start?

UPDATE:

`bundle exec rails s` works well but what is the correct way to setup ruby/rails and all the stuff, so `rails s` will work alone as well?

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv or some other ruby version manager?  For example, rbenv requires that you type `rbenv rehash` after installing gems with executables, like rails.  You may be running a rails gem that was installed for the system ruby otherwise.

Comment: show us the output from running `which ruby` and `which rails`, as right now you're using shortcuts to the actual executables given by your PATH.

Comment: how you install ruby? from source, rvm or rbenv?

Comment: @lain that makes sense. `which ruby` returns `/usr/local/bin/ruby` and `which rails` => `/usr/bin/rails`. A thing is that I've installed ruby in `/usr/local` and changed my PATH so that `/usr/local/bin` goes before `/usr/bin`. What can you suggest me? By the way I'm using Mac OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need run `rbenv rehash` if you are using rbenv.

Comment: I've installed it from source

Comment: I think problem in your $PATH. It's important to use ruby from source?

Comment: I don't know, it seamed as a best idea comparing to all the 3rd party stuff

Comment: I get `Could not find diff-lcs-1.1.2 in any of the sources`

Comment: `which gem`, `gem list | grep diff-lcs`, `gem environment`

Comment: ooohhh how it's hard to be a noob. I've installed `diff-lcs-1.1.2`, `jquery-rails-1.0.18`, `nokogiri-1.5.0`, `rspec-core-2.6.4`, `rspec-expectations-2.6.0`, `rspec-mocks-2.6.0`, `rspec-2.6.0`, `rspec-rails-2.6.1` and `webrat-0.7.3` and it finally started out with 1.9.3 ruby. But with a warning: `nsecure world writable dir /usr/local/lib in PATH, mode 040777`

Comment: `find /usr/local/lib -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` & `find /usr/local/lib -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Comment: Yes, it works good. But can you suggest some setup so everything will work well without execution from the _bundle_?

Comment: I think https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/ best way for developer, on production it's depend. and `bundle exec` it's right way, cause if you have rake 0.8.7 & 0.9.2 for example when you run `rake -v` it's been 0.9.2, but if you have project which need 0.8.7 and your gemfile have `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'` and you run `bundle exec rake -v` => 0.8.7. Sry for my bad English...

Comment: All you needed to do was type `bundle` to install all those dependencies in a single command, for future reference ;)

Comment: @d11wtq and Igor, I'm having troubles with **rvm** and **bundler** can you check it out? Because it's seams that your'e familiar with that stuff: [link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303404/rails-failing-and-strange-bundle-installations)