# Rails failing and strange bundle installations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, bundler

There's one thing that I can't figure out.

When I try to run `rails` it says something like:

```
Could not find sprockets-2.1.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

*By the way `sprockets-2.1.2` is installed. (I've run `bundle install` successfully)*

But as far as I understand when I run `rails` the global bin is being run and so my local gems installed by **bundler** are not accessible by it.

Can I solve this somehow without having to manually install a lot of gems like:

```
gem install what -v which?
```

I've already tried to run rails as

```
bundle exec rails …
```

And I had no luck :(

**I'm using RVM (if this can be the source of problem**

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @DylanMarkow yes. And each time it says `Your bundle is complete! Use \`bundle show [gemname]\` to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

Comment: Did you try `bundle update` ?

Comment: @megas yes, can that be a problem?

Comment: Try `bundle update`.  Install won't rebuild the dependencies if something is messed up.  Also, instead of `bundle exec rails`, try `./script/rails ...` just to rule out issues with it referencing the wrong rails (the script should do the equivalent thing).

Comment: @d11wtq `bundle update` haven't solved a problem. and `./script/rails …` is giving the same error

Comment: There's something wrong with your rvm install. I know this isn't the answer you'll want, but my advice to you is not to bother with rvm and to use rbenv (in conjunction with ruby-build).  It's much less voodoo. RVM is a big hairy beast when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm terribly sorry. There was some problem with RVM indeed. Probably because it was automatically installed by **JewelryBox** (OS X rvm gui). After reinstallation from terminal everything works like charm!

Conclusion: **JewelryBox is still buggy so at the moment it's bad idea to rely on it especially on *RVM* installation.**

Thank you everyone who've tried to help me!